# Inno Setup: Directive or parameter "Check" expression error: Invalid symbol '.' found

Tags: inno-setup

At the top of my script I am defining a version number of a dependency for a program.

```
#define ProductTestsVer "4.13.0.128"
```

I then use this identifier within the `Files` section in a `Check` function.

```
Source: src\ff\ProductTests.exe; DestDir: {app}; Check: RegCheck('Software\FFNVNTest\ProductTests', {#ProductTestsVer});
```

I then attempt to use the same `Check` function within the `Run` section, leading to the follow error:

`Directive or parameter "Check" expression error: Invalid symbol '.' found.`

I assume that I'm either making a stupid mistake or that you simply can't use identifiers within the `Run` section, but I highly suspect it's the former.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you are right. That syntax cannot (and does not) work even in the `[Files]` section. Tested with the latest Inno Setup 5.5.9 (both Ansi and Unicode).

If you check a preprocessor output, you will see that your syntax resolves to:

```pascal
RegCheck('Software\FFNVNTest\ProductTests', 4.13.0.128);
```

That is not valid Pascal Script code. You probably wanted:

```pascal
RegCheck('Software\FFNVNTest\ProductTests', '4.13.0.128');
```

So you need to use:

```pascal
RegCheck('Software\FFNVNTest\ProductTests', '{#ProductTestsVer}');
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, I knew I couldn't be far wrong. I guess the invalid `.` in the error was the `.` in between `4` and `13`. Thank you.